# Инъекции в куки

Tags: php, curl, cookie, авторизация

Пишу свой велосипед, который будет из себя представлять менеджер паролей для входа на сайты (да, знаю, что в браузерах есть куча готовых решений, но хочу разобраться в некоторых технологиях на практике).
На данный момент используя вот эти материалы: [первый](https://xdan.ru/avtorizacija-na-sajte-pri-pomoshhi-curl-php.html), [второй](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_kQN-3aNCeI).

Мне удалось сделать так, что я получаю от сайтов страницы, которые видят авторизированные пользователи, но когда я рендерю эту страницу в браузер или просто отправляю в браузер информацию, полученную из заголовков после авторизации через `cURL`, и еще раз вызываю страницу с нужного сайта, то в браузере меня отправляет на страницу логина. Собственно вопрос: можно ли как-то передать в браузер куки, полученные через `cURL` при авторизации, так, чтобы потом запрос на нужный ресурс не приводил к инициировании новой сессии?
Сейчас делаю вот так:

```
foreach ($cookies as $name => $value) {
    setcookie ($name, $value, 0, '/', 'site.domen.com');
}
```

Но в браузере я не вижу отправки нужных кук на сайт. Подскажите, кто хорошо знаком с этим вопросом, что я делаю не правильно? Или такое запрещено настройками безопастности?
На бек-энде использую РНР, но если есть рабочие примеры на других языках, то думаю, что разберусь)))

Comment: Не думаю, что серверу позволено менять чужие куки. Такая возможность была бы очень опасной.

Comment: Эта мысль меня тоже посещала, но материала, где было бы четко сказано, что это запрещено, я не встречал тоже. Хотя есть вариант, что встречал, но не понял, что мои желания несбыточны)

Answer (score 1):

Куки это просто заголовок запроса, который создатели http-клиентов (браузеров, например) договорились оправлять на сервер в определённых случаях. Один из способов (популярный, но не единственный) аутентификации пользователя на сайте заключается в генерации специального уникального секретного токена и передача его в заголовке `Set-Cookie`. Браузер, получив такой заголовок, сохранит токен и будет добавлять его к каждому следующему запросу. Так как токен уникальный, то сервер сможет аутентифицировать по нему пользователя.

Если немного поразмышлять, то станет понятно, что такую куку не хотелось бы показывать кому-то. Ведь если кто-нибудь украдёт секретный токен, то сможет делать запросы от имени пользователя-владельца куки (например рассылать сообщения его друзьям с просьбой скинуть денег на карту). Именно поэтому браузеры ограничивают доступ к кукам. И вы не можете получить доступ к кукам других сайтов.

Соответственно, чтобы реализовать то, что вы задумали, вам надо использовать [MITM-атаку](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0), но это уже не менеджер паролей. Вообще вся ваша затея выглядит очень странно. Менеджер паролей не осуществляет вход на сайты, он хранит пароли. Думаю если вы разберётесь в том, как это работает, то откажетесь от этой затеи.